# After Windows 10 installation, I get sent back to the "Install now" screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot

I am trying to do a clean installation of Windows 10 from scratch for a PC build that has an Intel Desktop Board DH67CL (motherboard). The processor is an i5 with a built-in graphics card.

At first I was using a MacBook Pro with Boot Camp Assistant to create a bootable USB drive and that **did not**  work. So, what I did was I used my Asus laptop and created another bootable USB drive and **that** worked. I was able to finally get the Windows 10 installation setup running.

Going a step further, after I deleted both partitions for hard drive 0 (system reserve as well as the main data drive) and installed Windows on one big unallocated partition, it worked. However, every time I finish installing it always leads me back to the "Install now" screen. It's as if I have not installed anything, and Windows 10 just won't boot after I installed it! I just keep getting taken back to the beginning where I am forced to reinstall it all over again (this happened about 10-12 times)! So I tried Windows Pro, Windows Home, with different variations and permutations and it still doesn't work. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

Just to double-check, did you actually *remove* the USB drive to avoid the install beginning again?

During the entire install scenario, early on in the process Windows will copy all the files it needs from the USB drive to your hard drive.  Typically after the first reboot, you can remove it.  If the installation process needs it again, it will ask for it.